# Can commercial aircraft dump luggage or cargo mid-air?

Tags: cargo, fuel-dumping

In a situation where the pilot realizes that weight of the aircraft is too high, can they dump luggage / cargo mid air, similar to dumping fuel?

Comment: For some reason I'm finding the image of an airplane pilot surreptitiously dumping the contents of the cargo hold to reduce weight hilarious!

Comment: And what's next, "Can airlines dump passengers or flight attendants mid-air"?  Oh my, I'm having trouble breathing here...

Comment: My question may seem stupid, but I have heard tales where airlines crashed due to excess weight.. So this led to my question...

Comment: This would be a nice feature for handling yappy little dogs.

Comment: Dear sir, your luggage is somewhere in Kansas. Sincere apologies, [signed] Delta.

Comment: Since the most likely time the pilot would notice the overweight condition would be shortly after takeoff when the plane is likely still over a populated area, I would think that safety concerns for property and people on the ground would prevent the plane from intentionally dropping heavy objects to the ground.

Comment: *"I have heard tales where airlines crashed due to excess weight.."*  I challenge you to cite any verifiable examples.   Small GA planes may get their weight wrong.  Airlines *never* do.

Comment: And if they do they don't stay off the ground for long.

Comment: @abelenky: In fact, in 2009 or 2010 an Emerates A340 with 300 passengers on board "got the weight wrong", did a tailstrike on takeoff and broke some things, and then dumped fuel to land again. There was no need to dump luggage. In fact, a mechanism to dump luggage sounds like a great way to make the airplane heavier and have less cargo capacity, plus points of failure.

Comment: @dotancohen:  You almost got me. :)  It didn't crash, but it is an otherwise horrifying tale:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirates_Flight_407

Comment: Even if they could jettison cargo mid-flight, what good would it do? Being overweight is mainly just dangerous on takeoff and landing. In particular, it can cause the 'landing' to occur immediately after the takeoff, as was almost the case with EK407. If you can takeoff and climb out successfully, then being overweight shouldn't be an immediate safety concern until you're landing. It will, of course, burn fuel faster than anticipated, which might force a diversion, but it shouldn't cause a crash. Also, EK407 wasn't overweight; they just calculated takeoff power incorrectly.

Comment: @Michael There's a scene from a John Wayne movie (The High and The Mighty) where the copilot chucks luggage out the back door of what I believe was a DC-4. Of course we're talking a propeller-driven unpressurized piston aircraft in that scenario, which is probably *not* what the OP had in mind when they posted this question :)

Comment: @abelenky One of the reasons for the crash of Air Midwest Flight 5481 was a stall due to excess weight: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Midwest_Flight_5481

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No they can't. The cargo doors are secured and will not open mid-flight.

Cargo holds are usually pressurized so opening the door anyway would cause depressurization.

Also if the weight was too high the pilot should never have lifted off in the first place.

Then after you theoretically throw the stuff off board think about what happens after to the stuff. It will drop down *hard* probably on someone's roof.

Only some military cargo planes with a back hatch are designed to jettison cargo.

Comment: So your answer is no... and yes...

Comment: @CGCampbell for airliners it is no, for specially designed cargo planes it is yes.

Comment: Thanks.... But there would not be much effect of de-pressurization if altitude is low... say 8k feet

Comment: @ratchetfreak AFAIK, those cargo planes also have people *in* the cargo bay to handle the drop (or to jump themselves, in the case of paratroopers); it's not something they can do from the cockpit.

Comment: @cpast - that is correct

Comment: I believe that the DC-10 had cargo doors that could open in mid-flight. Not that it was intentional!

Comment: @dotancohen Also, the [early 747s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_811).

Comment: Well they did it once at least. A hijacker parachutted?!! from a 727 in 1971

Comment: @jean That was via the stairwell in the tail cone from the passenger cabin, not the cargo hold.

Comment: @jean and that avenue was closed right after

Comment: "Also if the weight was too high the pilot should never have lifted off in the first place." Your answer seems to ignore the fact that sometimes airliners *do* find themselves overweight once in the air, and have fuel dump nozzles designed to handle just this situation.

Comment: @raptortech97 Different consequences though: Dumping fuel (via the dump nozzles) atomizes the liquid into the atmosphere. It's none too good for the environment, but it evaporates away long before it reaches the ground. If you chuck someone's Samsonite out of the plane it's going to be a solid mass of suitcase when it gets to the ground - with the airline's luck it will probably hit someone's new Lamborghini roadster.

Comment: Military cargo planes are designed to drop cargo (including humans) as regular operation, so I think it can't be counted as emergency dump. Just like road sander operation can't be called as "emergency jettisoning of cargo".

Comment: @raptortech97 that's usually because they have to divert and are too heavy to land safely rather than take off safely. While there have been instances of taking off overweight (sometimes with bad results) those stem from bad weight calculations rather than deliberately taking on too much cargo most of the time.

Answer (score 11):

There are various examples in history where luggage and/or cargo was dump during flight to reduce weight:

[Embraer EMB-110P1 Bandeirante, 29 July 1998](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19980729-0):

> To lose weight, the left overwing exit was opened and luggage of the passengers was jettisoned.

[Lockheed L-149 Constellation, 29 May 1972](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19720529-0):

> Cargo was jettisoned, but the aircraft continued to lose altitude.

Answer (score 0):

Today? No, not practical... aside from sudden depressurization, the high speed of the aircraft means that anything jettisoned from the aircraft stands a chance of striking tail surfaces with enough force to damage or destroy them.

Same goes for the cargo hold - it is also pressurized, with similar problems on sudden depressurization. Unintended opening of the cargo hold in flight has caused more than one crash, and several emergency landings.

In the early days of commercial aviation, dumping luggage due to low fuel was not unknown. In those days, aircraft were unpressurized, and flew through the weather, not over it. Aircraft speed was low, around 100-150kts, so things could be tossed out without risking damage to the tail. The lack of ILS at airports meant that those airports would close more frequently due to poor visibility. It was possible for an airliner, even with good fuel reserves, to run low on fuel if heavy fog closed all airports within the range of the aircraft. One way to keep the plane in the air longer was to dump luggage to lighten the aircraft.

In his book *Fate Is The Hunter*, Ernest Gann describes preparing to dump luggage from an ice encrusted DC2 - up to four inches thick in some places on the aircraft. They didn't take that step, but were prepared to.